# Drupal6: Anon doesn't have "view field_x" permission, but it still shows up in a view

Tags: drupal-6

In my Drupal6 site, I have a field called "**Short term attendance**". I have it set so Anon users are not permitted to view this field. (This permission is granted by the profile_permission module). However, I have a View where **short term attendance** is one of the fields. When Anon is looking at this View, it sees that field, in addition to all the others.

Do I have something set incorrectly, or is it time to bust out the sql rewrite hook?

Answer (score 0):

I thought I sent in an answer for this one, but here goes again...

Have you tried rebuilding the permissions at admin/content/node-settings? It could be that your permissions cache is corrupted.

Actually, this could be the cause of your other issue with 'Add Content' showing for anon users as well.

Comment: this doesn't work. The issue is unchanged by rebuilding the permissions cache. (Although I guess that's not surprising, considering that that was the "Node Access" permission cache, which probably doesn't have anything to do with individual fields.